# Wordpress: get all posts of a custom type

Tags: wordpress

I have this strange issue. I want to fetch all posts that are of a custom type, here's my snippet.

```
$query = new WP_Query(array(
    'post_type' => 'custom',
    'post_status' => 'publish'
));


while ($query->have_posts()) {
    $query->the_post();
    $post_id = get_the_ID();
    echo $post_id;
    echo "<br>";
}

wp_reset_query();
```

This only gets me 6 of them, while I have more than 50 records matching that criteria in the database. Can anyone tell me where I have gone wrong?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 54, accepted):

`'posts_per_page' => -1,`

Add this to the WP_QUERY array of arguments and it should return all of the posts of this custom post type.

Answer (score 49):

This get all posts of a custom type using `get_posts`:

```
$posts = get_posts([
  'post_type' => 'custom',
  'post_status' => 'publish',
  'numberposts' => -1
  // 'order'    => 'ASC'
]);
```

Comment: So much better than WP_Query. Thanks :)

Comment: @Rob: WP_QUery and get_posts are subtly different. if you need pagination for example get_posts will not help you much (you can't tell total posts number for example).

Answer (score 8):

The number of posts to return are set under settings > reading

You can pass the number of posts for your query to return using.

```
'posts_per_page' => 'number of posts'
```

Answer (score 2):

You should never use:

```
'posts_per_page' => -1
```

It slow and not effective, if you are talking about SQL Query speeds. So it is much better to use some large integer.

> This is a performance hazard. What if we have 100,000 posts? This could crash the site. If you are writing a widget, for example, and just want to grab all of a custom post type, determine a reasonable upper limit for your situation.

More details here:
https://10up.github.io/Engineering-Best-Practices/php/#performance

Comment: The concern is valid but the suggestion makes no sense whatsoever. "So it is much better to use some large integer." This will have 0 impact on performance until there are more posts than this interger. But in that case the query won't match all the posts anymore, which is specifically what OP is asking for.

Comment: You failed to answer the question here. If using `'posts_per_page' => -1` is a bad practice, why didn't you include an appropriate practice in this answer?

Answer (score 0):

It is advisable to use an integer instead of '-1' For example:

```
'posts_per_page' => 999999,
```

Comment: Why is it? You should give reasoning so as to distinguish from personal preference.

Comment: Wow.. 6 downvotes for suggesting a more optimal solution. While `'posts_per_page' => -1,` isn't wrong, but it can cause performance issues if the number of records are large. Using a number like 999999 or any other number that is higher then your max records in database is optimal.

Comment: The performance impact is not because WP somehow gets very slow by the number -1... It's because you're asking WP to get a large amount of posts out of the database. If you take this number to always be higher than the amount of posts, you will be retrieving the same amount of posts as though the query has `'posts_per_page' => -1`and, consequently, the performance will be identical.

Comment: Do not answer for what is not asked in the question. If you have a better answer give a valid reason.