# get posts query wordpress

Tags: wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

i try to get posts via query wordpress
i need to fetch the posts thats's in spacfic taxonamy

[تصميم تطبيقات](https://roeia.com/%d8%aa%d8%b5%d9%85%d9%8a%d9%85-%d8%aa%d8%b7%d8%a8%d9%8a%d9%82%d8%a7%d8%aa/)

```
<?php
            get_query_var('taxonomy');
            $taxonomy = 'eposd_category';
            $terms = get_terms($taxonomy); // Get all terms of a taxonomy

            if ( $terms && !is_wp_error( $terms ) ) :
            ?>
            <?php foreach ( $terms as $term ) { ?>
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                <div class="item">
                    <div class="load">
                        <?php echo z_taxonomy_image($lug term->term_s); ?>
                        <div class="load-icon text-center">
                            <a href="<?php echo get_term_link($term->slug, $taxonomy); ?>"> <i class="fa fa-play"></i></a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="item-content">
                        <h2><?php echo $term->name; ?></h2>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        <?php } ?>
<?php endif;?>
```

[تصميم العاب](https://roeia.com/%d8%b4%d8%b1%d9%83%d8%a9-%d8%aa%d8%b5%d9%85%d9%8a%d9%85-%d8%a7%d9%84%d8%b9%d8%a7%d8%a8/)

Comment: possible duplicate, I think this q/a will help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25237430/wordpress-get-all-posts-of-a-custom-type from there you can just add the taxonomy to the arguements

Comment: this link also may help https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/165610/get-posts-under-custom-taxonomy